# How to make a button CSS change only IF form fields are valid

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, button

Currently my site has only a form and a button. The button contains a paper plane svg and some javascript that makes the plane fly off when the button is pushed.

What I need:

- The plane to fly off (CSS to change) only **IF** the form fields above are valid (name, email, message).
- Add a 1 second delay before submitting the form.

Right now the button is changing even though the fields are stating "this field is required" and the form has not submitted.

Here is a demo of [my site](http://taskbasket.net/public/demo.html) Click the button and see.

**I know that `p` tags shouldn't be within `button` tags, but the text in the button won't change (plane won't fly) unless `p` tags are used for some reason. If I remove the 'p'
from this line within *index.js*  `$('button p').text(function(i, text)` the plane won't be seen flying away**

The HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php" class="signin"> 

     <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Your Name" />   
    <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Your Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)"/>
   <textarea name="message" id="message" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Your Comment or Question" required></textarea>


 <button>

 <p>CLICK HERE</p>
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="paper-plane-icon" d="M462,54.955L355.371,437.187l-135.92-128.842L353.388,167l-179.53,124.074L50,260.973L462,54.955z
M202.992,332.528v124.517l58.738-67.927L202.992,332.528z"></path> 
  </svg>
</button>

  <script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>


  </form>
```

and index.js is:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  $('button p').text(function(i, text) {
    return text === "Why sent??" ? "Why Sent??" : "Why Sent??";
  });
});
```

How do I make the plane take off only **after** validation/submission _ a 1 second delay? Thank you kindly

Comment: I recommend to you using 'keyup' not 'click' to input fields.
just my opinion :)

Comment: Why did my question get downvoted?

Comment: I dunno. Maybe someone dislike your question style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a JS Validation Library as a fallback to HTML5 Validation ([jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) is pretty neat).

Either way, listen for submit event on the form (if using $.validation use the submitHandler config key).

```
$('form#youId').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){
        // your fliying animation
        // when your flying animation ENDS
        e.target.submit(); // this SENDS the actual form.
    }, 1000);
});
```

### EDIT

see this [Working Example](http://pastebin.com/6BWacLAi).

**REMARKS on your demo**

- Your demo didn't have jQuery Validate js file included, so it failed on .validate() method invocation.
- Also Your demo got a missing `});` which produced an `Unexpected End of Input` error.

New demo uses a custom Event to trigger form submit after animation has ended (actually when 1sec past after triggered).

Comment: Thanks you but can you be specific how I apply your code: I edited my form tag to be  <form method="post" action="submit.php" id="contactform" class="signin"> so it has id 'contactform'. Then I used your code like this just before the closing body tag: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#contactform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){
        // your fliying animation
        // when your flying animation ENDS
        e.target.submit(); // this SENDS the actual form.
    }, 1000);
});

</script>     -- but it won't work

Comment: You can see the updated demo here (not working)  http://taskbasket.net/public/demo.html